# Why doesn't AskDifferent Reviews have tests?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I have stopped by the review page on StackOverflow a few times, and noticed that they give test questions and answers for the reviewer to catch - typically flag - correctly.

This particular one was in the Late Answer review queue:
[image: Late Answers test]

Obviously, it is a post worthy of a moderator flag. I saw that and clicked to flag it, but then was told that I passed the test.

I think this is a really nice feature: would it be possible to have on AskDifferent as well, or have I just never been tested for some reason?

Comment: The main stack overflow has slightly different rules for review as well as orders of magnitude more traffic, flags, posts, etc... so some things we see on a blue moon happens daily or even hourly on Stack Overflow. Since this is something more geared to the site owners, we might need to wait for them to answer even if it's a vague - we're not going to document exactly how tests work to prevent gaming them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @bmike says each site does this differently. In Stack Overflow the tests were added because there were many users trying to get review badges by just clicking Looks Good even when the question was obviously bad or vice versa, These questions attempt to catch those doing this. See several Meta Stack Overflow questions

In Ask Different we do not have enough reviews for people to get the higher review badges (ie requiring more that one review so there is no incentive to game the system by just pressing the button without actually reviewing.

Also I haven't seen any complaints in Ask Different about incorrect reviews.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the info.

Comment: We are working to point out things that we catch when looking at the review history - especially if there is a pattern of people choosing to close a question as "too localized" for instance when that reason doesn't really apply. I agree we don't have large problems, but our reviews could be better in some cases.